# Google storage operations extremely slow when using Customer Managed Encryption Key

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We're planning on switching from Google managed keys to our own keys (working with sensitive medical data) but are struggling with the performance degradation when we turn on CMEK. We move many big files around storage in our application (5-200GB files), both with the Java Storage API and gsutil. The former stops working on even 2GB size files (times out, and when timeouts are raised silently does not copy the files), and the latter just takes about 100x longer.

Any insights into this behaviour?

Comment: When using CMEK, you are actually using an additional layer of encryption on top of Google-managed encryption keys and [not replacing them](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys#overview). As for gsutil, if your moving process involves including the objects’ hashes then [gsutil will perform an additional operation per object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/UsingEncryptionKeys#performance-implications-for-encryption-keys), this might explain why moving the big files is taking much longer than usual.

Comment: About the Java Storage API, my first thought would be to increase the timeout, however since you have already tried it and it didn’t fix the problem, I will need more information regarding your set-up using the Java Storage API. Tell me more about how Java storage API is used and how your setup is.

Comment: As a workaround, you may instead use [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#upload-resumable). This type of upload works best with large files since it includes the option of uploading files in multiple chunks which allows you to resume an operation even if the flow of data is interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, figured out what was going on with the Java API I was not properly calling getResult on my CopyWriter so the operation just wasn't completing.

Comment: Great! Good to know that it is now resolved. A member of our team would add some of information in my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using CMEK, you are actually using an additional layer of encryption on top of Google-managed encryption keys and [not replacing them](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys#overview). As for gsutil, if your moving process involves including the objects’ hashes then [gsutil will perform an additional operation per object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/UsingEncryptionKeys#performance-implications-for-encryption-keys), this might explain why moving the big files is taking much longer than usual.

As a workaround, you may instead use [resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#upload-resumable). This type of upload works best with large files since it includes the option of uploading files in multiple chunks which allows you to resume an operation even if the flow of data is interrupted.